# How to calculate the difference in daily averages based off their names?

Tags: r, dataframe, calculator, difference

I have a dataset that shows values for daily averages in Aug and Sept. There are 6 rows that occur in August and 6 in September. I need to compare the daily averages between `"LoggerID_Sitecodes"` that have the same "SiteCode" (i.e. `"X1WR"`, `"X3WR"`, `"14WR"`). for example I need to know what the daily difference was between `"X1WR_S_Stationary"` and `"X1WR_U_Compare"` in August, and again in September. Here the data frame I'm working with

```r
Summary_Stats_ShieldComparisons = structure(list(month = c("Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep"), LoggerID_SiteCode = c("X20676906_X1WR_S_Stationary", "X20817726_14WR_S_Stationary", "X20819740_X3WR_S_Stationary", "X21092860_X3WR_U_Compare", "X21092863_X1WR_U_Compare", "X21092877_14WR_U_Compare", "X20676906_X1WR_S_Stationary", "X20817726_14WR_S_Stationary", "X20819740_X3WR_S_Stationary", "X21092860_X3WR_U_Compare", "X21092863_X1WR_U_Compare", "X21092877_14WR_U_Compare"), `1` = c(19.7973541666667, 19.8387604166667, 20.18475, NaN, NaN, NaN, 20.7902604166667, 20.8141354166667, 21.2830104166667, 21.2929479166667, 20.8281875, 20.8101458333333 ), `2` = c(19.167875, 19.485, 19.0699166666667, NaN, NaN, NaN, 19.5951979166667, 19.5447395833333, 20.1386770833333, 20.1535416666667, 19.5912395833333, 19.52684375), `3` = c(19.1635833333333, 19.4361041666667, 18.6934895833333, NaN, NaN, NaN, 19.5257083333333, 19.1441145833333, 19.5713333333333, 19.59909375, 19.5366041666667, 19.1539791666667 ), `4` = c(20.58890625, 21.04803125, 20.2363854166667, NaN, NaN, NaN, 18.35540625, 18.3098854166667, 18.50115625, 18.4912708333333, 18.3722708333333, 18.313875), `5` = c(20.4786875, 21.2495, 20.0483333333333, NaN, NaN, NaN, 17.5555208333333, 17.3981666666667, 17.3645416666667, 17.34075, 17.57234375, 17.4060729166667), `6` = c(20.6277291666667, 21.5976875, 19.65246875, NaN, NaN, NaN, 17.1620833333333, 17.2158333333333, 17.0411875, 16.9986041666667, 17.1630520833333, 17.2089166666667 ), `7` = c(21.0440729166667, 22.0925729166667, 20.3653333333333, NaN, NaN, NaN, 18.9051145833333, 18.4130833333333, 18.1541875, 18.1224479166667, 18.9368854166667, 18.4041041666667), `8` = c(21.0748229166667, 22.6307708333333, 21.0419166666667, NaN, NaN, NaN, 18.93325, 18.6943020833333, 19.1433645833333, 19.0987708333333, 18.9830104166667, 18.6754791666667), `9` = c(21.2133541666667, 21.96090625, 20.8293333333333, NaN, NaN, NaN, 18.92021875, 19.3938541666667, 18.8428645833333, 18.82209375, 18.9281354166667, 19.39384375), `10` = c(21.0549583333333, 21.5886666666667, 21.0386875, 21.0903333333333, 21.07584375, 21.6045833333333, 19.9498854166667, 20.2733333333333, 18.5902604166667, 18.8200729166667, 19.9508958333333, 20.2773125), `11` = c(22.0971145833333, 22.28015625, 21.6225625, 21.6523645833333, 22.1451458333333, 22.3070625, 19.29984375, 19.7349166666667, 19.4305729166667, 19.5128333333333, 19.3048229166667, 19.7180520833333), `12` = c(22.6818854166667, 23.1176041666667, 22.5744375, 22.5664479166667, 22.7099166666667, 23.135625, 18.51884375, 18.83503125, 18.70721875, 18.7646979166667, 18.5287604166667, 18.8320625), `13` = c(23.9690625, 23.7686458333333, 24.0393958333333, 24.0303541666667, 24.0491770833333, 23.7916979166667, 18.8686354166667, 18.9042916666667, 18.8498229166667, 18.8508333333333, 18.8785520833333, 18.9013229166667), `14` = c(24.3618229166667, 24.29590625, 24.8081979166667, 24.7779375, 24.41753125, 24.3341666666667, 17.8340520833333, 17.648875, 18.26125, 18.24240625, 17.8538645833333, 17.6330104166667), `15` = c(25.377125, 24.76175, 25.80578125, 25.7824791666667, 25.4849166666667, 24.76578125, 16.7127291666667, 16.5705833333333, 17.227625, 17.1958854166667, 16.7285833333333, 16.5765208333333), `16` = c(23.89946875, 23.3866354166667, 25.5114895833333, 25.4689583333333, 24.0171145833333, 23.384625, 18.32178125, 18.0413645833333, 17.95309375, 17.9134479166667, 18.32771875, 18.0601875), `17` = c(23.0580416666667, 22.281625, 24.908625, 24.8368958333333, 23.1826041666667, 22.2736875, 18.36525, 17.6020625, 17.84609375, 17.8045, 18.40496875, 17.5951458333333 ), `18` = c(22.2622708333333, 21.6921875, 23.8456979166667, 23.7704791666667, 22.35740625, 21.7041145833333, 20.0287604166667, 19.6535729166667, 19.1127291666667, 19.0949270833333, 20.04965625, 19.66053125), `19` = c(21.6695416666667, 21.6125520833333, 22.6521354166667, 22.6231145833333, 21.7014166666667, 21.6076041666667, 19.3356666666667, 19.4366041666667, 19.649625, 19.60590625, 19.370375, 19.4296458333333 ), `20` = c(20.8732916666667, 21.1062604166667, 22.2158020833333, 22.1788958333333, 20.897125, 21.10825, 17.3488333333333, 17.1304583333333, 18.2068125, 18.1503020833333, 17.3944270833333, 17.1155729166667), `21` = c(21.9709166666667, 21.60440625, 23.2420416666667, 23.2148854166667, 22.0552291666667, 21.6133854166667, 16.7735104166667, 15.9922083333333, 17.9162708333333, 17.8567708333333, 16.8260729166667, 15.9743125), `22` = c(22.2590520833333, 21.9096041666667, 23.1308229166667, 23.0857708333333, 22.3375, 21.9086354166667, 17.0556875, 16.09653125, 17.7455625, 17.6989895833333, 17.11028125, 16.07759375), `23` = c(22.3858125, 21.9991770833333, 23.0202604166667, 22.9752395833333, 22.4510104166667, 22.0151770833333, 18.7368229166667, 17.5346458333333, 18.8792916666667, 18.841625, 18.7895104166667, 17.5237604166667), `24` = c(23.7411979166667, 23.0992604166667, 24.2068645833333, 24.1847708333333, 23.8049479166667, 23.11025, 18.79309375, 17.82234375, 19.183, 19.14334375, 18.8576979166667, 17.8034895833333), `25` = c(25.13925, 24.0122291666667, 25.8055104166667, 25.775125, 25.2316770833333, 24.0142291666667, 18.4624479166667, 18.1642395833333, 18.9538333333333, 18.8943645833333, 18.4753333333333, 18.15734375), `26` = c(25.3103645833333, 24.1949895833333, 26.4140208333333, 26.3784270833333, 25.4208854166667, 24.20096875, 18.8378854166667, 18.5516770833333, 18.3652083333333, 18.3018645833333, 18.8388958333333, 18.5368333333333), `27` = c(24.9939166666667, 24.2193541666667, 25.419875, 25.37846875, 25.0889375, 24.23046875, 18.4467083333333, 17.9333125, 18.7626770833333, 18.7200625, 18.4794375, 17.9254270833333)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Essentially, I want the end result to look like this table, but for the values to be the difference between sites. Can anyone help?

Comment: Thank you for including the dput output! However, it doesn't look like the data set posted correctly - we're missing at least one closing parenthesis and the formatting is a little wonky.

Comment: @Dubukay, it worked for me, though the way SO was rendering it, it was easy to miss one when copying it. I've posted a suggested edit to the OP's question, I hope it now works for you.

Comment: @KristenCyr, I think I understand what you mean by "same SiteCode", but that is encoded internally in strings. I'd recommend breaking it out as its own column, as normal grouping mechanisms (to do what you've asked) will be clunky when operating on substrings. Further, I suggest we don't need 27 numbered columns to demonstrate the point, I'd think 3-4 would suffice. Lastly, while you mention "daily" the only thing we see is "monthly", is that what you meant?

Comment: (Or is your use of `"X1RW"` as a sitecode just an abbreviation for the entire string within `LoggerID_SiteCode`?)

Comment: So the numbers at the top of the columns are the days... which is where I'm getting daily averages. But I kept the months because I also need to know months. This format I will be keeping because it's important for what I'll be doing in the future. And yes, my use of site code is just an abbreviation for the entire string

Comment: The code you edited isn't working for me, I think there's a bracket missing

Comment: Okay, thank you for that clarification ... I'm going to recommend shifting to a long-mode for this, realize that having it "wide" will not work perfectly with all months ... and it's easy to re-shape back to wide. As far as the code, I just tested a *third* time and highlighting all of that code block and pasting in my R session *works*. But feel free to revert the edit if you feel the need.

Comment: ok, sounds good. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm confused about your desired output: at one point it sounded like you needed diffs day-to-day, which is row-wise, but then you say you want to see differences *between* sitecodes, which suggests a row-to-row thing. Please fill in at least a few days' worth of your actual expected values and paste that within the question.

Comment: So I want the daily differences between the sites that have a similar site code... so I don't need a daily difference between ```X1WR``` and ```X3WR```. Instead I need differences between ```X1WR``` and ```X1WR_Comparison``` then ```X3WR``` and ```X3WR_Comparison```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, it is easiest to change to long format to get the differences, then pivot back. Here, I first extract the relevant site code (e.g., `X1WR`), so that we can group by the site code. Then, I pivot the data to long format, so that we can then get the difference for each group (i.e., by `month`, `site`, and `day`). Then, I pivot it back to the long format. I used absolute value for the difference, but you can remove the `abs` if you don't need it.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(qdap)

Summary_Stats_ShieldComparisons %>%
  mutate_all( ~ replace(., is.nan(.), NA)) %>%
  mutate(site = genXtract(LoggerID_SiteCode, "_", "_")) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(site = first(site)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-LoggerID_SiteCode) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(`1`:`27`), names_to = "day", values_to = "value") %>%
  group_by(month, site, day) %>%
  mutate(diff = c(abs(diff(value)))) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  distinct(diff) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(as.numeric(day)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "day", values_from = "diff") %>%
  arrange(month)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 29
  month site       `1`      `2`      `3`      `4`      `5`       `6`      `7`     `8`        `9`
  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Aug   X1WR  NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA        NA       NA      NA        
2 Aug   14WR  NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA        NA       NA      NA        
3 Aug   X3WR  NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA        NA       NA      NA        
4 Sep   X1WR   0.0379   0.00396  0.0109   0.0169   0.0168   0.000969  0.0318   0.0498  0.00792  
5 Sep   14WR   0.00399  0.0179   0.00986  0.00399  0.00791  0.00692   0.00898  0.0188  0.0000104
6 Sep   X3WR   0.00994  0.0149   0.0278   0.00989  0.0238   0.0426    0.0317   0.0446  0.0208   
# … with 18 more variables: 10 <dbl>, 11 <dbl>, 12 <dbl>, 13 <dbl>, 14 <dbl>, 15 <dbl>, 16 <dbl>,
#   17 <dbl>, 18 <dbl>, 19 <dbl>, 20 <dbl>, 21 <dbl>, 22 <dbl>, 23 <dbl>, 24 <dbl>, 25 <dbl>,
#   26 <dbl>, 27 <dbl>
```